# Adding eventListener to flex screen

Tags: apache-flex, event-listener

I want to add an eventListener who listens to DoubleClick event of the flex screen. Following is my code

```
private function zoomIn(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    svg.scaleX+=.02;
    svg.scaleY+=.02;
    Alert.show("Inside Zoom Function");
}


var svg:SVGDocument = new SVGDocument();
svg.parse(re.result as String);
chart.addChild(svg);
svg.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK,zoomIn);


<mx:Canvas id="canvas" height="100%" width="100%">
<mx:UIComponent id="chart" width="100%" height="100%"/>
</mx:Canvas>
```

However double clicking on screen is not resulting in going inside the zoomIn function. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Please define "Screen"?  Does the SVGDocument class dispatch the double click event? As a general rule; Flex containers do not dispatch mouse events; some user interactable control must do so.

Comment: I checked it, and yes it doesn't dispatch any MouseEvent. What will be my next possible choice then?

Comment: You could extend the SVGDocument class so it would handle double click events.

Comment: Hierarchy of classes is like SVGDocument->SVGContainer->SVGElement->Sprite. As Sprite dispatches mouse events for clicks when buttonMode is set to true, why is it not working?

Comment: A bit out of my realm, but a sprite needs "something" inside it to dispatch events. I had a lot of problems with transparent portions of FXG elements not dispatching events.  Is that your problem here?

Comment: Thanks @www.Flextras.com. Problem is resolved now. I changed `private function zoomIn(event:MouseEvent):void` to `private function zoomIn(event:Event):void` and it is working now. Still I don't know why MouseEvent had problem and Event works.

Comment: Were you getting a runtime error of any sort?  You should post your solution as a formal answer to the question.

Comment: No, I was not getting any error. However my zoomIn function was not getting called. Added the formal answer.

Comment: My intuition is that something else was going on.  Changing the method signature of an event handler would not make the event start firing.  Are you sure you had the debug version of Flash installed?   Perhaps there was a runtime error you weren't seeing?

Comment: Yes, you are right. That was not the issue. SVGDocument is not handling DOUBLE_CLICK event but it is handling CLICK event. I will change my answer.Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVGDocument was not handling DOUBLE_CLICK event. However it can handle events like CLICK or MOUSE_WHEEL. So I changed the code as following. This is working.

```
svg.parse(re.result as String);
chart.addChild(svg);
svg.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL,zoom);
```